# Accord.net and 100metres run

Tags: c#, machine-learning, accord.net

I very like c# and .net environment despite a machine learning here is not popular well. So i choosed accord.net, seems it is great library to start. But i don't have any experience at that topic.
At first i'm gonna try to calculate which runners will be first with only "Talented" and "Speed" data:

Position|Player|Talented|Speed
Run 1:
1|Coleman|yes|50
2|Gatlin|yes|38

Run 2:
1|Bolt|yes|51
2|Blake|no|47

How to train it and after that enter 2 players data to see which will be faster?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're looking to get a machine learning algorithm to do here, but principally you'll first need a body of training data. Do you have historical race data you can use to train this model or are you going to make it up? How do you defined "Talented"? Additionally, you may get your question closed as being too broad as your are more essentially asking "how do I use machine learning algorithms" which isn't a good question for the stack overflow format.

Answer (score 0):

The [Accord.NET website](http://accord-framework.net/) contains examples for most of the [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) classifiers. For example to use [Naive Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) check the souce code of the following link:

http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_Bayes_NaiveBayes.htm

All the classifiers can be found here:

http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/R_Project_Accord_NET.htm (in the Accord.MachineLearning Namespace)

Of course you will need training and test data